# Not getting reponse text with Ext.Ajax.request

Tags: extjs

I am requesting url by Ext.Ajax.request() method but it's does return any response text from server while I paste that url in browser url (direct access) than get response text in window.

can you tell me what is issue with that URL?

```
 Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: "myurl",
                method: 'GET',
                timeout: 60000,
                success: function (response) {
                    alert('response : ' + response);
                },
                failure: function (response, opts) {
                    console.log('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
                }
});
```

Comment: Can you provide the code of your AJAX call?

Comment: update question with code.

Answer (score 1):

The success function's parameter is an [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#response) **object**, so you cannot just alert it.

To access the actual response text you need to access the object's [responseText](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-responsetext-attribute) property:

```
success: function(response) {
    alert('response : ' + response.responseText);
}
```

Comment: Could you post the error message? Is the URL you're trying to access on the same host/port as your script ([Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy))

Comment: same url as per Same-origin policy, but that url response data with browser but not with Ext.Ajax.request. it return no error message with status code 0 with request with Ext.Ajax

Answer (score 0):

response is not any string. so you can't alert it directly. you will see [object object] in alert.

so see response object try 
`console.log(response);`

you will get your actual data in `response.responseText`